# How to clone form element in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML form:

```
<form>
<div>Add</div>
<div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="name">
</div>
<div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="phone">
</div>
</form>
```

How I can clone this form that I will get two fields `ng-model="name"` and `ng-model="text"`.

So, I want send to server two values of `ng-model="name"`

**I tried:**

Angular JS:

```
$scope.forms = 2;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="itm" ng-repeat="item in forms">
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
</div>
```

It gives me nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model:

```
$scope.users = [
    { 
        name: 'John',
        phone: '098097770'
    },
    {
       name: 'Alice',
       phone: '765876598'
    }
];
```

In your view:

```
<form name="editUsersForm">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.phone"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

That's a basic rule in angular: the model is the single point of truth. The view is generated from the model.

Here's [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Cc381qGHbElysvcaXsz?p=preview) demonstrating it.

Comment: So, I can add new element in `Object` and after use `user`

Comment: what does that mean? for each user in the array $scope.users, you will have the corresponding two inputs in the view. What you type in the inputs is bound to the user object in the array.

Comment: I need show a new input blocks when I click to link.

Comment: So, make sure the link adds a new user object to the $scope.users array. The view will update itself accordingly.

Comment: You're doing something that doesn't make any sense, and that hasn't got any resemblance to my answer and to the working plunkr I posted. WHY? ng-repeat doesn't work like you think it works. Read the documentation.

Comment: Can I use` $scope.forms` like as numer, not object?

Comment: No, you can't. You want several users each having their name and phone, so you need an array of users. Not a number.